# How to render a markdown partial with Assemble?

Tags: gruntjs, markdown, assemble

I'm trying to render a Markdown partial using Assemble. I've setup my Grunt task as follows:

```
assemble: {
        options: {
            flatten: true,
            partials: [ 'src/_inc/**/*.hbs', 'src/_content/pages/*.md' ],
            layoutdir: 'src/_layouts',
            layout: 'default.hbs',              
        },
        pages: {
            options: {
                data: 'src/_data/pages/*.json',
            },
            files: {'public/': ['src/pages/*.hbs']}
        },
    }
```

I can easily reference any partial from that folder by simply doing `{{>partial_file_name}}` and it works just fine, but when I try to parse it as markdown, it won't work.

```
---
title: <%= home.title %>
---

<p>Source:</p>

<pre>{{>home}}</pre> <--- this works fine and returns the source code of home.md

<p>Rendered:</p>

{{md 'home'}} <--- this DOES NOT output anything!
```

I also tried doing `{{md home}}`, `{{md home.md}}` and `{{md 'home.md'}}` but none of them worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `{{md './home'}}`?

Comment: I believe that using `{{md './home'}}` is just referencing hard-coded path - which in this case would point to the same directory as the template that references it? Anyway, I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the markdown block helper:

```
{{#markdown}}
  {{> home }}
{{/markdown}}
```